# How we apply condition on 'This' event in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This code use to display text and picture's in jquery language by slide and confirmation message. In this code I faced a problem that to hide the picture call by id by using fun that when we say ok then it hide the picture otherwise it did not hide the picture...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<!--we add jquery library file-->
<script src="test.js"></script>
<!--fun applied on text & images-->
<script>
//apply on text
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $('h1,h2').show('slow')
    })
//apply on image that call by class
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.img').click(function()
                    {
                        alert("You did not hide this Picture!");
                    }
            )
    })
$(document).ready(function() 
{
$('#img').click(function() 
{
    let shouldHide = confirm("Are You Sure To Hide This Picture?");
    if (shouldHide)  
{
        $(this).hide('slow');
    } else 
 {
        return;
    }
})
 })
</script>
<!--apply  to clean the screen-->
<style type="text/css">
    h1,h2
    {
        display: none;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
   <!--display the image with class and id-->
   <img src="images/1.jpg" width="400" height="500" id="img">
   <img src="images/2.jpg" width="400" height="500" class="img">
   <!--Display text by slide-->
   <h1>How Are you?</h1>
   <h2>I'm fine....</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `confirm` method of JavaScript

```
    $('#img').click(function () {
        if(confirm("Are you sure?"))
        {
            $(this).hide('slow');
        }
    });
```

Also you can't use `break` when you're not in a loop.

Tell me if it worked for you!

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to write two same functions make it as one.

```
//apply on text
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $('h1,h2').show('slow')
    })
//apply on image that call by class
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.img').click(function()
                    {
                        alert("You did not hide this Picture!");
                    }
            )
    })
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#img').click(function () {
            if(confirm("Are You Sure To Hide This Picture?"))
            {
                $(this).hide('slow');
            }
        })
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

confirm returns boolean value which you need to decide whether to hide or not and you cannot use break; inside the function, you should use return; instead.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<!--we add jquery library file-->
<script src="test.js"></script>
<!--fun applied on text & images-->
<script>
//apply on text
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('h1,h2').show('slow')
    })
    //apply on image that call by class
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('.img').click(function() {
            alert("You did not hide this Picture!");
        })
    })
    //apply on image that call by id
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#img').click(function() {
        let shouldHide = confirm("Are You Sure To Hide This Picture?");
        if (shouldHide) {
            $(this).hide('slow');
        } else {
            return;
        }
    })
})
</script>
<!--apply  to clean the screen-->
<style type="text/css">
    h1,h2
    {
        display: none;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
   <!--display the image with class and id-->
   <img src="images/1.jpg" width="400" height="500" id="img">
   <img src="images/2.jpg" width="400" height="500" class="img">
   <!--Display text by slide-->
   <h1>How Are you?</h1>
   <h2>I'm fine....</h2>
</body>
</html>
```